# Why is my event handler bound with jQuery not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any ideas why this doesnt work in my php document? 
When i tested this on jsfiddle, everything worked fine.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("a").click(function() {
            $("div.info").hide();
            $("div." + this.className).show();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="shipping-container">
        <a href="#" class="ups">Show UPS info</a>
        <a href="#" class="fedex">Show Fedex info</a>
        <div class="ups info" style="display:none">the info for ups</div>
        <div class="fedex info" style="display:none">Who let the dogs out</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Jules: Can't believe [no-ones used the title before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104914/add-title-uniqueness-to-the-heuristics-for-detecting-low-quality-questions/106796#106796)!

Comment: @Matt you made a much better job of the title than I did ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the script before the link element exists.

In jsfiddle the code is by default placed in an event that runs after the document is loaded. Use the `ready` event to do this in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function() {
    $("div.info").hide();
    $("div." + this.className).show();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You missed the document ready handler, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            $("div.info").hide();
            $("div." + this.className).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively, leave your `script` tag as it is, but put it at the end of the document, before the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that your JQuery code is only loaded AFTER your DOM has fully loaded by doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("a").click(function() {
       $("div.info").hide();
       $("div." + this.className).show();
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this in your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
      $("div.info").hide();
      $("div." + this.className).show();

});
</script>
```

This will ensure that all of the DOM objects (especially the a elements) are loaded before you try to attach any event handler.